# Scraping html WITHOUT uniquie identifiers using python

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to design an algorithm using python that scrapes thousands of pages like [this one](http://www.puntingform.com.au/form-guide/horses/regal-acclaim/) and [this one](http://www.puntingform.com.au/form-guide/horse-jockey/b-cross/), gathers all the data and inserts it into a MySQL database. The script will be run on a weekly or bi-weekly basis to update the database of any new information added to each individual page.

Ideally I would like a scraper that is easy to work with for table structured data but also data that does not have unique identifiers (ie. id and classes attributes).

Which scraper add-on should I use? [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) or [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)?

Are there any particular tutorials/books I should be looking at for this desired result?

In the long-run I will be implementing a mobile app that works with all this data through querying the database.

Comment: So are you (in effect) asking whether the lack of unique identifiers makes some options bad, that would be good in the presence of unique identifiers?

Comment: The three things you asked about are not otherwise-equivalent alternatives; one is a parser, once is an automated crawler that also parses, and one is a stateful browser emulator that also parses. It's like saying that your house doesn't have smooth walls and then asking whether you should use the paint from Home Depot, a local vinyl siding installer, or a home improvement company.

Comment: Do you want the javascript/CSS to line up properly? is it needed?

Comment: Basically. I don't want to waste time writing code for a scraper that is inefficient and slow. I don't have much experience with scraping (this will be my first attempt at implementing a complete script) and I'm not sure how to gather data from a table attribute (td, tr, th, etc.) that has no identifier.

Comment: @Back2Basics Yes, i need everything to line up as it looks in the browser.

Comment: @NicholasLaw: the "normal" way to handle *ML data (where * can be X or HT or even SG) that doesn't have identifiers on the elements you care about, is to first shove it through a parser library and then write logic to find the important elements. There's more than one way to do that. In the case of BeautifulSoup look at the advanced options to `findAll` and also remember that you can find one node, then do more searches on its children. Other parsers will give you easy access to the delights of XPath, CSS selectors, jquery selectors, and various other competing ways to search an element tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thought:
(in order to save some time) Have you seen thewaybackmachine?  http://archive.org/web/

2nd thought:
If you are going to develop a mobile app then the layout of this site doesn't lend itself to be put on handheld devices easily.  I would suggest not bothering with the webpage portion of this.  You are just going to have to dig all the information out eventually and change your scrappers each time they change some little thing on their website.

You can get the data from [their developer API](http://www.puntingform.com.au/developer/api/) in Json or CSV format.

From the raw data you can make it into whatever format you want.  (for personal use only according to their site)

Caveats:
Pay attention to the robots.txt file on the site.
http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

If they don't want to be scrapped they will tell you so.  You can do this for personal use, but if you try making money from their content you will find yourself sued.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lxml](http://lxml.de/), which can take [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) specifiers. It takes a while to get used to the XPath syntax, but it's useful in cases like this.